# videoView shows only stopped movie

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview

I made a fragment with following code:

```
class play_video : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video)
    val vidView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoView)
    val vidController = MediaController(this)
    val viduri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+packageName+"/"+R.raw.test1)
    vidView.setVideoURI(viduri)
    vidView.start()
}
```

}

It shows the first frame of video and plays sound, but the video was not played and it only shows stopped image.

Is there anything I did wrong ?

The file name of the movie file is 'test1.MOV'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format `.MOV` is not supported.

Check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

I suggest to convert your video with one supported. If you don't know how to convert a video use `ffmpeg` https://ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Wow. Never knew that. Thanks a lot.